# I get a 404 NOT FOUND error when trying to use a ngrok server

Tags: http, server, ngrok

I'm currently using webstorm to program my webpage and when I open it through Google chrome and host it locally, the url the browser uses is

http://localhost:63342/assignment2/statichtmlpage-edit.html?_ijt=nqejipcmjnaun1b1416leu6a2i

When I open Terminal in order to host it on ngrok, I type in ./ngrok http 63342
and then a window opens with the ngrok url that I can use
but when I go to that URL (http://4038e733.ngrok.io) all I get is a 404 NOT FOUND error.

I'm not sure why this is happening, any help would be appreciated

[image: Terminal screenshot]

Comment: can you try using a different port (say, 8080) to start your server, then start ngrok with `./ngrok http 8080`?

Comment: also, make sure you access the full URL, e.g. `http://4038e733.ngrok.io/assignment2/statichtmlpage-edit.html?_ijt=nqejipcmjnaun1b1416leu6a2i`

Answer (score 0):

Access your page with the **full** URL:

```
http://4038e733.ngrok.io/assignment2/statichtmlpage-edit.html?_ijt=nqejipcmjnaun1b1416leu6a2i
```

Add your path to web (`.html`) files after the `http://4038e733.ngrok.io/` page.

---

You were hosting from the root directory `http://localhost:63342/`, but forgot to point to a file. So as expected, the error:

> ```
> GET /           404 Not Found
> ```

Is saying there is no file at the root directory.

I'd imagine the fix for most users is to append `/index.html` to the end of their ngrok link:

```
http://ngrok.io/ ... /index.html
```